# SQL QUERY UPDATE CONDITION

Tags: sql

I need to add one condition to this query :

```sql
UPDATE o36t_orders s 
SET s.bonifico = EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM mytable d 
                         WHERE d.Descrizione_operazione 
                         LIKE CONCAT('%', s.shipping_number,'%') )
```

The condition should be to **do the update only if `s.bonifico != 1`**

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  `= EXISTS` is just not a common SQL construct.

Comment: Add a WHERE clause with the condition.

Comment: UPDATE o36t_orders s 
SET s.bonifico = EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM mytable d 
                         WHERE d.Descrizione_operazione 
                         LIKE CONCAT('%', s.shipping_number,'%') AND s.bonifico  != 1)

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is this:

```
UPDATE o36t_orders s 
SET s.bonifico = EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM mytable d 
                         WHERE d.Descrizione_operazione 
                         LIKE CONCAT('%', s.shipping_number,'%') )
WHERE s.bonifico != 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for your problem:

```
//CONNECT DB - FETCH RESULT
$variable=$row['s.bonifico'];
if($variable!='1'){    
UPDATE o36t_orders s SET s.bonifico = EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable d WHERE d.Descrizione_operazione LIKE CONCAT('%', s.shipping_number,'%') )
}
```